# Bug with flash player loading xml in chrome

Tags: xml, flash, google-chrome

I have a flash player loading a team page using an xml. It is working in all browser but doesn't work in Chrome?

The loading bar appear but stop at the beginning. 
The url for the xml file is correct.

Does anyone have an idea of why?

Comment: Without more info, not even the slightest bit of code, or an error log - how can we have any?

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX and I'm using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64. The file is on the remote server and not local. It was working before and now it is not working properly. here is the url ... http://www.kelvin-emtech.com/fr/equipe/administration.sn

Comment: The file does not run correctly for me, either, but the XML seems to load OK (if it's the equipe_administration.xml you are talking about). What's different is that the load process somehow seems to stall.  I've decompiled your SWF and taken a brief look at the load routine... If you ask me, that's probably where the problem is: Something is wrong, either with the way you are processing the XML content, or how you're handling load completion. Try breaking smoothImageLoad() down into smaller methods, make things more readable, and use the content debugger plugin to track down the problem.

Comment: I would bet it's the event handling. Since you've used frame scripts, it might be load order (top down vs. bottom up), or perhaps it's related to speed (e.g. things happening quicker in the other browsers, thus triggering an event correctly, while the slower browser misfires,...). There's just too many possibilities - you will have to trace your way in towards the problem.

Comment: We think the new flash player have a problem with the fact that our flash use xml and that it is loading a couple of other small flash. The problem is now on all my browser. I've updated my local flash player  yesterday to the latest version.

Comment: That just underlines my assessment: You are using AS2, and we've come a long way since then.  Newer versions of the plugin tend to be faster, so perhaps that is part of the problem. The XML loads correctly, and the script itself works for me on other browsers than Chrome - so there *has* to be some issue that relates to timing. As I said: Try to refactor your code into smaller methods, simplify, debug and trace until you find the error; it is almost at 100% certainty **NOT** a Flash Player bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing locally? Chrome denies access to local files through the flash interface unless you launch chrome with special privileges. I know how to do this in OSX using the terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I'm sure there is an equivalent way in windows too.

Comment: We are on a remote server. It seems it is a problem with the last update of chrome. I now have the same problem with two different client. Flash player don't want to load the xml.

Comment: I've had a lot of various issues with chromes new "pepper" flash player. disabling it and using the regular player fixed a lot of the issues for me. Although this is not a good fix as obviously our users are not going to go through such a process. Look into some of the issues with chromes pepper flash as it might be related.

Comment: I don't think that's really the issue.  I use the content debugger plugin (not a Chrome-specific one), and the program wouldn't work for me, either.